# Is it possible to give reputation points to another user?

Tags: support, reputation

I was in the process of [editing what was a good and eventually accepted suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/370431/download-entire-album-from-google/385195#385195) when it was deleted for being just a link.  That was why I was editing it, because it was the right link it just needed a lot more explaining.
 I absolutely love the link and never would have known about it without the original post and it seems unfair that I get all the points.  I wouldn't mind sharing them if there is a way to do so.
I have also had times when a quick answer was made exponentially better in edit by someone else that I though it would be nice to share some rep.

Comment: Just being able to "give away" rep would kind of defeat the point.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. My thoughts ran more toward sharing with someone whose edit totally changed the quality of an answer, or someone whose comment adds a whole other dimension to the completeness and quality of the resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to really give users more reputation than a few upvotes is a [bounty](https://superuser.com/faq#bounty). If you really liked his answer, then you could suggest to him to post it again, or just go to his profile and upvote a few answers.

You cannot just give away reputation though, it can only be earned through questions, answers, bounties, and edits.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much ditto what Simon said, just a few more points:

Giving reputation could be too easily and obviously abused and there are already sufficient mechanisms for people to get reputation equal to the amount of effort they put into the site and specific questions and answers. Missing one question here or there, even for a new member, shouldn't be a shattering thing.

Simon's suggestions are good though: Finding a users other answers and up-voting them, and encouraging a re-post and drawing attention to it.

I'm generally against throwing the baby out with the bath water, but in this situation it is a small thing to lose a question here or there that didn't have enough effort put into it. The good user will learn and grow and produce better, more thorough answers in the future. So much the better when they are aware of such unique and useful things as this particular user does.